# XPath query to get javascript arguments

Tags: php, xpath, onclick, arguments

I've just started using XPath queries in php and while a lot is very self-explanatory I'm wordering if it's possible to get the values of an onclick() function.

An example

```
<a id="moreButton" onclick="showMore('#content','/page/2');">Show More</a>
```

The best I have come up with is `//a[@id='moreButton']/@onclick` which returns `showMore('#content','/page/2');`

Can I further refine it to only return `/page/2` or will I just have to use php to parse what I have?

Comment: Actually, the two wanted arguments can be produced by evaluating XPath expressions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must parse it with something else, XPath doesn't understand JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

**Actually, this *can* be produced by evaluating the following XPath expressions**:

**For the first argument of the function specified in the `onclick` attribute:**

```
substring-before(substring-after(/*/@onclick, '('), ',')
```

**For the second argument of the function specified in the `onclick` attribute:**

```
substring-before(
     substring-after(substring-after(/*/@onclick, '('), ','),
     ')'
                )
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "substring-before(substring-after(/*/@onclick, '('), ',')
   "/>
  ===========

   <xsl:copy-of select=
   "substring-before(
         substring-after(substring-after(/*/@onclick, '('), ','),
         ')'
                    )
   "/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<a id="moreButton"
  onclick="showMore('#content','/page/2');">Show More</a>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
'#content'
===========

'/page/2'
```